# Centos: yum install ffmpeg fails?

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

I'm trying to install ffmpeg on my server.

The problem is that when i run the following command:

```
yum install ffmpeg
```

I get the following error:

```
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: dag. Please verify its path and try again
```

I have this is in `etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Centos
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
enabled=1
```

I know the issue is the `http://apt.sw.be` as they are down...

I cannot find an alternative mirrors for it... could someone please let me know if there are any working mirrors for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Dag/rpmforge is dead](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge). Just [download a static binary of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)  or [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) instead of using an old, outdated repository.

Extract it from the archive file and move it to `/usr/local/bin` if you want it available to all users, or just `~/bin` if you don't have superuser/root.